# Adding sum of array with pushed input values

Tags: javascript, html

I have pushed an input value to an empty array and converted it into a number. I am trying to add up the array and show the sum. But the whole array is shown and no addition has been done. I've included some of the code here but I'll also include the JS fiddle in case I forgot something important. I may be overthinking it as I have been looking at it for sometime.
 **JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/nzart/emruz0sb/4/

```
// HTML
<h1>Sugar Counter:</h1><p id="total">--</p>

<div class="box bot1">
 <div class="twogrid mid">
  <label for="amount">Amount of Sugar</label>
  <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
 </div>    
</div>

//JS
var added = [];

//Get Data
var userInput = function(){
    return parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
}

// Store Data
var newSugar = function(){
    return added.push(userInput());
}

//Add total
function total() {
    var sum = 0;    
    for (var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {
        sum += added[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = added;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the last line in `total()` be `document.getElementById('total').textContent = sum;`? You are using the array `added` itself instead of the `sum`

Comment: `document.getElementById('total').textContent = sum` instead of `document.getElementById('total').textContent = added;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect inside of function total():

```
 document.getElementById('total').textContent = added;
```

Change to this:

```
document.getElementById('total').textContent = sum;
```

Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bqt1mws7/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the **array variable** not the **sum variable**. Assign the **sum** variable to #total, not **added** variable.

document.getElementById('total').textContent = sum;

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the addition process. If the array is valid, the `total()` function will work well. But at the last statement of `total()` function, you put `added` variable as output. But it should be the value of `sum` variable.

```
function total() {
    var sum = 0;    
    for (var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {
        sum += added[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('total').textContent = sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a button to perform the summation to update the total.

The `Array.prototype.reduce` function is a easy way to total values inside of a list.

```
values.reduce((runningTotal, currentValue) => runningTotal + currentValue, initialValue)
```

```js
var valueList = [];

document.getElementById('btn-add').addEventListener('click', onAddClick);

function onAddClick(e) {
  var value = getCurrentValue();
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    alert('Value is not a number!');
    return;
  }
  valueList.push(value);
  document.getElementById('total').textContent = getTotal();
}

function getCurrentValue() {
  return parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value.trim());
}

function getTotal() {
  return valueList.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // Sum the values in the list
}
```

```html
<h1>Sugar Counter:</h1>
<label>Total:</label>
<span id="total">--</span>
<div class="box bot1">
  <div class="twogrid mid">
    <label for="amount">Amount of Sugar</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="btn-add" />
  </div>
</div>
```